# Force Into Something

Tags: word-usage

According to this [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/force_2), the verb "*force*" seems to have these two usage patterns:

> p1. force somebody into doing something
>   p2. force somebody into something

Examples from that dictionary illustrating the two usages are:

> e1 The President was ***forced into*** resigning.
>   e2 Ill health ***forced*** him ***into*** early retirement.

Example sentence e2 suggests that pattern p2 can only be used with a state noun (in retirement) and not an action noun (resignation).   So, does that mean that this:

> The president was ***forced into*** resignation.

is wrong?

Comment: RE: _Example sentence e2 suggests that pattern p2 can only be used with a state noun (in retirement) and not an action noun (resignation)_. What a crazy assertion! An example sentence is just that, an example sentence. Just because one example sentence follows a particular structure doesn't mean all sentences must follow that structure.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the actual definitions of ***[force](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/force_2)*** in the dictionary you referenced:

> 1 [often passive] to make somebody **do something that they do not
>   want to do**

This definition refers to a force against the ***will*** of another person.

> *The president was ***forced*** into resignation. (Against his will)*
>
> - **Resignation** is a noun, used as the object of the preposition *into*.
>
> *The President was **forced** into resigning. (Against his will)*
>
> - **Resigning** is a noun form (gerund) of the verb resign, used as the object of the preposition *into*.
>
> *The President was **forced** to resign. (Against his will)*
>
> - **To resign** is the infinitive of *resign*, used as an adverb.

All three sentences can have the same meaning:

*The President didn't want to resign, but something overcame his will.* The passive voice "was forced" is often the signal of this meaning. Just about any kind of adverb can modify *was forced*, and action adverbs work particularly well, because people can be forced **to do things** against their will.

---

The second definition of **force** shifts the focus a little bit:

> 2 to use physical strength to **move somebody/something into a
>   particular position**

Now the definition refers to a strong person (or thing) moving another person (or thing) into a position:

> *Bad weather forced the plane to land.*
>
> - *Bad weather* is the strong thing, *plane* is the thing being forced, and "*to land*" is the position.
>
> *Ill health forced him into early retirement.*
>
> - *Ill health* is the strong thing, *him* is the person being forced, and *retirement* is the position.

The first sentence is a thing forcing another thing, so there is no "will" involved. The second sentence is a thing forcing a person, so maybe the meaning of *forced* is a **combination** of the first two definitions. Either way, you can use the same three methods to modify *forced*:

> *Ill health forced him into early retirement. (Against his will?)*
>
> - **Retirement** is a noun, used as the object of the preposition *into*.
>
> *Ill health forced him into retiring early. (Against his will?)*
>
> - **Retiring** is a noun, used as the object of the preposition *into*.
>
> *Ill health forced him to retire early. (Against his will?)*
>
> - **To retire** is the infinitive of *retire*, used as an adverb.

Answer (score 0):

"Resignation" is a state, the state of having resigned. So "the president was forced into resignation" is perfectly valid.

"Resignation" can also be a process. "I submitted my letter of resignation."

That said, the word "resignation" is ambiguous. It can mean that someone has quit a job or office, or it can mean that someone has given up. That is, if you say, "After six failures, Bob fell into a state of resignation", you mean that he no longer has hope of succeeding.